# Tile caching not working

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, tomcat

In my GeoServer I want to cache tiles for a layer. But when I am trying to seed tiles for a layer I can see the status as stated the image below.

> Tiles completed is -1.

I am refreshing but it still seems -1.

[image]

I cannot understand what the problem is or it is caching tiles or not. Also I cannot find any log in Tomcat log file (catalina.out).

Comment: You do not give enough details about what you have been done. Does seeding work for some of the demo layers which are installed with GeoServer? What kind of layer is that geonode:national3? Do you use some of the standard gridsets?

Comment: Try looking in the GeoServer log data_dir/logs/geoserver.log